# WPF datagrid control binding enables, but takes 2 clicks on the control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

Sorry about the pretty meticulous question but I am pretty stuck.

I have a `datagrid`, inside the `datagrid` are two column controls a `checkbox`, and a `datetime picker`. I have binded the `datetime picker` to only be enabled when the `checkbox` is checked. It's working.. except the `datetime picker` is not activated right away, I have to click inside the date time picker column twice for it to enable. Immediately after checking off the `checkbox` i make sure the `checkbox` checked value is correct, and it is. I am trying to just polish my form and this is annoying me. Any help is appreciated!

My XAML Code:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyCheckBox" Width="60">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding checkboxChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Reminder Date" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <xctk:DateTimePicker Format="Custom" FormatString="M/d/yyyy h:mm" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=checkboxChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                             Value="{Binding checkboxDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Additional info: I also tested this button on other controls like a text box, it also takes 2 clicks inside the text box to enable it. Also the date time picker is part of the extended `WPF` toolkit but that doesn't seem to matter since it happens for other controls.

EDIT: ISSUE RESOLVED... It's really late at night ... I forgot to add a call for the checkboxChecked property to PropertyChanged in my object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @EliArbel, can you add your comment as an answer and can you mark it as the correct answer Ben, so that this question can be marked as answered please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add a call for the checkboxChecked property to PropertyChanged in my object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.